# Как реализовать плагины/компоненты в laravel?

Tags: laravel

Всем привет. Работал как то с october cms, и там была очень удобная разбивка кода на плагины. Т.е создал плагин, внутри него уже модели, вьюхи, контроллеры. И потом у плагина можно было создать компонент и  встроить в любое место шаблона. Вопрос такой, можно ли сделать подобное на чистом ларавеле, и как? есть может пакеты какие то? Пробовал несколько модульных компонентов, но они не позволяют встраивать это куда либо

Comment: Если вы уверены, что вам нужна такая инкапсуляция, то можете попробовать сделать своё пакет. При желании его можно будет даже опубликовать, а дальше устанавливать через composer в других проектах. Так и гуглите - laravel создать пакет.